# C equivalent to java.util.regex

Tags: java, c, regex

I've built a program in Java to translate a assembly code to machine code, I'm using this regex to do it:

```
^((?<label>.*):)?\s*(?<instruction>\w+)(\s+(?<op1>\w+))?(\s+(?<op2>\w+))?(;\s+(?<comment>.*))?$
```

I've tried to use standard regex.h, if I take the group names out it compiles but does not work because the optional groups `()?` are treated as select groups...

It's really hard to search in Google because everything is about C# and not C. I understand that Java, Python, JavaScript or even C# would make my life easier, but I need to do it in C. If I can't use regex, it will become a `sscanf` challenge.

Is there a way to convert this regex to C regex or there is a C equivalent for `java.util.regex`?

Comment: I don't believe C, as distinct from C++, has a standard regex library. So you need to tell us what library you're using. (For instance, [the GNU one?](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) If so, which interface?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had some luck using [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) for complicated regexes from C or C++. 
It's pretty widely used and compliant. It used to have some issues with unicode data, but it looks like some of those have been resolved now.

PCRE supports named captures as used in your example using the `pcre_copy_named_substring` function.

Comment: Anyway, you read the regex incorrectly. `(?<label>.*)` is a capturing group, named `label`, which captures text matched by `.*`. Same for `(?<op1>\w+)`, which is a capturing group labelled `op1`, capturing text for `\w+`. Do note that the OP is writing the regex in Java. As far as I can see, the regex can be taken over to PCRE without change.

Comment: Ugh thanks @nhahtdh - too early in the morning for me ;) But this is good news since PCRE supports named capture groups too... So I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much this would help and how much work you would have to put into this. But why don't you take a look at the Java source code for [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) to see how this is build. If that's what you want, then you just have to translate into C.